# Using knocking and knocked

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

looking at below sentences which of these look more correct

> my genes came knocking last night

which means i was craving for some home food

> my genes knocked me last night

that means i have to prepare my fav dish

Comment: I am afraid neither of them makes much sense to me as the phrase _my genes came knocking_ is not familiar to me. Can you edit to give my context as to where you found it?

Comment: “knocked me” would more likely be used in the sense of receiving a blow. “He knocked me down”, “The news knocked me into a loop.” It would not be used in the sense you are using it except in some idioms where it is followed by “up”. “She knocked me up.” might mean she banged on the door to wake me from sleep. “He knocked me up.” might mean he made me pregnant. Avoid unless you are very sure you understand the implications of the message you are sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Came knocking" (or in its full form, "*came knocking at the door*") is an idiom - a **figure of speech**. It means that something *presented itself*, for example, "*fortune came knocking at the door*".

I understand you're trying to say that you have a genetic disposition to craving food and that craving presented itself.

Although "knocked" is the past tense of "knocking", replacing it in your example context would not make sense as the idiom is lost.

In a **literal** context, it would be fine:

- The postman came knocking at my door last night.
- The postman knocked at my door last night.

Comment: Thanks so much!!